# Reformat item with line feeds from a CSV file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a *csv* and I would like to know how to replace newline by `-`, just in the *brothers* column, with `bash`:

```
name,brothers,age,adress
------------------------
john,"marc
peter
paul
alex",18,street
thomas,mike,20,place
```

Comment: You need a proper CSV parser, and Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask for recommendations for one in `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk is perfect for this

```
 awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{while ( match($0,/"[^"]+"/,a) ) {gsub(/\n/," ",a[0]); print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[0]; $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} print}' your.csv
```

outputs:

```
me,brothers,age,adress
------------------------
john,"marc peter paul alex",18,street
thomas,mike,20,place
```

Answer (score 0):

Ungainly combo of `csvtool`, `sed`, & `bash`:

```
csvtool pastecol 2 1- \
        input.csv 
        <(csvtool col 2 input.csv | \
          sed -n '/"/,/"/{:a;N;$!ba;s/\([^"]\)\n/\1-/g;};p') | \ 
csvtool trim r -
```

Output:

```
name,brothers,age,adress
------------------------
john,marc-peter-paul-alex,18,street
thomas,mike,20,place
```

Except for the `sed` part, it's not that bad.  `csvtool` replaces column *2* with an edited copy.  At the end it trims an extra comma that `csvtool` stuck in there.